# Multiple WordPress sites installs sharing the same database but with different content and domains

Tags: database, installation

I was wondering if it is possible to have multiple WordPress websites installed using the same database and database user.

For example, I have site 1 and site 2 - www.site1.com and www.site2.com respectively. Both will have different content. Can I install both sites to share the same database and database user? Assuming I am unable to create a db and user for each website.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can do it.

You use two different prefixes for both sites in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress multisite